# Encountering error while connecting to UnificationEngine Server over 443 HTTPS

Tags: unificationengine

I am encountering error during handshake while trying to use the certificate for HTTPS connection to apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/user/list 
Configuration Setup:
[HTTPS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJYt5.png)

Certificate Used for connection:
[Server Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ2n7.png)

Error:

```
    HttpClient.request: request failed: unable to establish connection to apiv2.unificationengine.com:443 - IPcon: SSL session failed with error: "SapSSLSessionStartNB()==SSSLERR_SSL_READ
  SSL:SSL_read() failed  (536875072/0x20001040)
  => "received a fatal SSLv3 handshake failure alert message from the peer"
>> ---- SecuSSL ErrStack: ----
0x20001040 | SAPCRYPTOLIB | SSL_read
SSL API error
received a fatal SSLv3 handshake failure alert message from the peer
0xa0600266 | SSL | ssl3_read_bytes
received a fatal SSLv3 handshake failure alert message from the peer
0xa0600266 | SSL | ssl3_read_bytes
received a fatal SSLv3 handshake failure alert message from the peer
<< ---------------------------
  SSL:SSL_get_state()==0x2120 "SSLv3 read server hello A"
  SSL NI-hdl 3: local=10.117.96.122:51038  peer=10.117.18.16:8080
  cli SSL session PSE "#_MemPSE_#153191466869762214968424"
  Target Hostname="apiv2.unificationengine.com"
"
```

Appreciate your help to resolve this issue. Please advise if you need more information on this.

Thanks & Best Regards,

AP

Answer (score 1):

Unificationengine will support all TLS version not ssl2 or ssl3

Comment: Does this mean it doesn't support SSL2 and SSL3 ?
Thanks, Anand

Comment: Just read about TLS (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/how-to-determine-if-a-browser-is-using-an-ssl-or-tls-connection) and it is nothing but SSL3.0. Does it mean that Unificationengine supports TLS1.1/1.2 but not TLS1.0 ? Please clarify. Thanks, Anand